# Trigger rendering of all `content-visibility: auto` elements BEFORE a user scrolls to them without blocking main thread for >50ms

Tags: javascript, html, css, optimization, layout

I want to have a fast page-load but also not have the user see a delay before content is rendered while scrolling down the page.

I have a large html page with many `<dl>` elements.

To speed up page load, I have set `content-visibility: auto` in css. See https://web.dev/content-visibility/

```
dl {
  content-visibility: auto;
  contain-intrinsic-size: 1000px;
}
```

Due to the complexity of the contents of the `<dl>`s there is a noticeable delay when a user scrolls while the `<dl>`s are rendered as they come into the viewport.

Thus, soon after page-load I want to render all the offscreen `<dl>` straight away (before a user scrolls to them) but in such a way that it does not block the main thread and scrolling remains responsive.

So, I want to set `content-visibility: visible` on the `<dl>`s starting from the top one, and not blocking the main thread (for more than say 50ms). So, maybe allowing user interaction after rendering each `<dl>`.

So, I need a version of the below, that doesn't block the main thread:

```
document.querySelectorAll('dl').forEach(function(dlElement, currentIndex, listObj) { dlElement.style['content-visibility'] = 'visible' });
```

---

My use case: My page is of math notes, which I want all on one page to reduce friction.  I use katex which (for now, before we can use mathml on chrome) produces very large and complex html, which even server-side rendered still takes a lot of time for layout and rendering on the browser.

Comment: It seems that content-visibility is not supported on Firefox or Safari - does that matter or are you only having to support Edge/Chrome?

Comment: For now, I'm happy to target Edge/Chrome. If necessary, I can serve mathml to Firefox or Safari.

Comment: I have found that when `dlElement.clientHeight != 1000px` then "something" has clearly happened but I'm not sure if this is "something" is style, layout or paint.  However, I'm happy to try with this as the condition before moving on to set the next `<dl>` to visible. How do I do this?  I've tried various combinations of setTimeout, and requestAnimationFrame but it appears that I'm still blocking the main thread.

Comment: I'm going to try this but it may take me a while: 75% through the page: Using requestIdleCallback to make DOM changes https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/08/using-requestidlecallback

Answer (score 0):

Rather than leave this unanswered, let me paste my (unperfected) code I have been testing for the last few weeks.

```js
// --------- Shim requestIdleCallback if not supported in browser ----------------------------------

window.requestIdleCallback =
  window.requestIdleCallback ||
  function (cb) {
    var start = Date.now();
    return setTimeout(function () {
      cb({
        didTimeout: false,
        timeRemaining: function () {
          return Math.max(0, 50 - (Date.now() - start));
        }
      });
    }, 1);
  }

window.cancelIdleCallback =
  window.cancelIdleCallback ||
  function (id) {
    clearTimeout(id);
  }

// Global
let isRequestIdleCallbackScheduled = false;
let nodeToRemove = null;
let isVisualUpdateScheduled = false;
let totalDlElementsLeftToShow = 0;

function startIfNeeded() {

  totalDlElementsLeftToShow = document.querySelectorAll('dl:not([style*="content-visibility: visible;"]), .ra:not([style*="content-visibility: visible;"]').length;

  if (totalDlElementsLeftToShow > 0) {
    console.log('Not a mobile - Let\'s make things visible when we are next idle');
    scheduleVisibilityChanges();
  }
  else {
    console.log('Apparently, all visible');
  }
}

function scheduleVisibilityChanges() {

  // Only schedule the rIC if one has not already been set.
  if (isRequestIdleCallbackScheduled) {
    //console.log('returning because idle callback scheduled');
    startIfNeeded();
  }

  isRequestIdleCallbackScheduled = true;

  //console.log('scheduling visibility changes when next idle or in 30 seconds at the latest');

  requestIdleCallback(processHiddenElements, { timeout: 30000 });
}

function processHiddenElements(deadline) {

  // Since our operation takes a while, we only want to go ahead if we have at least 50ms.
  while (deadline.timeRemaining() > 49 && totalDlElementsLeftToShow > 0) {

    // console.log('time remaining is ', deadline.timeRemaining(), '- scheduling next visual update');

    // Don't set content-visibility immediately wait for the next
    // requestAnimationFrame callback.
    scheduleVisualUpdateIfNeeded();
  }

  // console.log('Deadline reached, will check again the next time the user is idle if there are more events still to send');

  if (totalDlElementsLeftToShow > 0) {
    requestIdleCallback(processHiddenElements, { timeout: 30000 });
  }
}

function scheduleVisualUpdateIfNeeded() {

  if (isVisualUpdateScheduled) {
    // console.log('returning - visual update already scheduled')
    return;
  };

  isVisualUpdateScheduled = true;

  // console.log('requesting animation frame');

  requestAnimationFrame(setContentToVisible);
}

function setContentToVisible() {
  // console.log('changing visibility of element ');

  let completeHiddenNodeList = document.querySelectorAll('dl:not([style*="content-visibility: visible;"]), .ra:not([style*="content-visibility: visible;"]');

  // We chunk the layout changes
  let i;
  let numberToChunk = 20;

  if (completeHiddenNodeList.length < 20) {
    numberToChunk = completeHiddenNodeList.length
  }

  for (i = 0; i < numberToChunk; ++i) {
    completeHiddenNodeList[i].style.contentVisibility = 'visible';
  }

  isVisualUpdateScheduled = false;
  isRequestIdleCallbackScheduled = false;
  totalDlElementsLeftToShow = totalDlElementsLeftToShow - numberToChunk;
}

if (!navigator.userAgentData.mobile) {
  startIfNeeded();
}
```